# Can I put buttons in SimpleCursorAdapter listView?

Tags: java, android

I want to put two buttons in listView.

```
   public class Imenik extends ListActivity {

@Override
public long getSelectedItemId() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return super.getSelectedItemId();
}

@Override
public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
}
ListView lv;
Cursor Cursor1;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //create a cursor to query the Contacts on the device to start populating a listview
    Cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
      null,
         null,
         null,
         null);
    startManagingCursor(Cursor1);

       String[] from = {
         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID}; // get the list items for the listadapter could be TITLE or URI

 int[] to = {android.R.id.text1,
    android.R.id.text2}; //sets the items from above string to listview

 //new listadapter, created to use android checked template
 SimpleCursorAdapter listadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, Cursor1, from, to );
 setListAdapter(listadapter);

 //adds listview so I can get data from it
 lv = getListView();
 lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

}
```

}

with this code I get all contacts names and numbers and put in the list, but I want two buttons and in every row checkBox, and user can click on item - mark checkBox and click confirm button to get those values in an array.
Help, thank you, Wolf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And again...

Build a custom Adapter that uses your data...

> Whenever you want to do processing with the views in a ListView you
>   need to create a custom adapter that will handle your logic
>   implementation and pass that information to the views as necessary.

Example

http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/

Answer (score 0):

If you not want  to make customAdapter Then Two things you do for button handle(***its not effect to onitemclick and onitemlongclik*** )

1. In xml file  just ***android:focusable="false"*** in buttonview

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_name"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="TextView"
           android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_city"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="TextView"
           android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_phone"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/button_selector1"
           android:text="TextView" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/bt_button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Button" 
           android:focusable="false"/>
   ```
2. In simple cursor adapter

   private void showdataquery() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   ```
       mhelper = new DAtahelper(this);
       db = mhelper.getReadableDatabase();

       String columns[] = { "_id,name,city,phone" };

       Cursor c = db.query("vishal", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
       c.moveToFirst();

       String[] from = { "name", "city", "phone" };
       int[] to = { R.id.tv_name, R.id.tv_city, R.id.tv_phone };
       SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
               getApplicationContext(), R.layout.showdata, c, from, to, 0) {

           @Override
           public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               return super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
           }

           @Override
           public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub


               return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
           }

           @Override
           public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               final int row_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")); //


               Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_button);


               button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View arg0) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       Log.i("button click","button");
                   }
               });

           }

       };

       lv_database.setAdapter(adapter);

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
           long arg3) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Log.e("", "long");
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       Log.e("", "item");

   }
   ```